# Como extraer un valor de un bucle en ejecucion?

Tags: python, while

Buenas tardes y saludos a todos, estoy intentando realizar un programa en python el cual necesito que en cualquier momento de la ejecución de un bucle pueda extraer el valor en el instante,

aqui dejo una porcion de codigo que me va a dejar explicar lo que necesito, el proyecto es un poco mas grande y lo voy a ir subiendo conforme avance.
Se trata de un script que lee las cadenas que envia un gps bluetooth y las reenvia a un cliente tcp local, de modo que tengo un servidor tcp enviando constantemente los datos y un cliente que cada vez que se ejecuta recibe la cadena y se cierra.
El problema que estoy teniendo es que cuando ejecuto el script de cliente me muestra los datos atrasados conforme avanza el tiempo, tal cual en este codigo que pongo:

```
import time

def extraer(i):
    num = int(input())
    if num > 1:
        print(i)
    
i = 0
while True:
    i += 1
    time.sleep(1)
    extraer(i)
```

En este código, cada vez que ingreso un valor mayor a 1, me devuelve el contador del bucle while, lo que necesito es que el bucle siga contando, y cada vez que yo ingrese el numero me devuelva el valor de ese momento.

Disculpen la redacción, soy nuevo en el foro
Saludos y gracias

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Tu pregunta es muy amplia, es necesario que agregues el código de lo que estás haciendo. Puedes leer [mcve] como guía. Saludos

Comment: Asi planteado es muy amplio. Reducelo a un caso específico e ilustralo con código.

Comment: Editado @MauricioContreras

Comment: Editado @CandidMoe

Comment: No se entiende claramente... El `input()` va a detener la ejecución del programa hasta que el usuario escriba algo. Entiendo que esto es un ejemplo para emular lo que ocurriría en realidad, que es que el dato se leería de alguna interfaz bluetooth. ¿Lo que quieres es que no se detenga en el `input()`? ¿Que si no hay dato disponible regrese al bucle para que de este modo se pueda seguir contando? Pero no veo la relación entre esto y lo que cuentas de que te muestra datos atrasados. Quizás sea mejor que pongas el código real (aunque lo simplifiques)

Comment: @abulafia , el gps se conecta via bluetooth y envia varios datos en cadenas de carcteres cada 1 segundo en grupos separados por coma y lineas, lo que deberia hacer el codigo es que cada vez que yo ejecute el codigo de cliente en otra consola, me envie los valores de velocidad y termine el programa. Lo que me esta pasando es lo que decis, y tal cual en este ejemplo, se detiene aguardando input(), el gps sigue enviando cadenas de caracteres. Voy a ver si puedo simplificar un poco el codigo original y lo subo. Gracias

Comment: @GabrielPerez. No se entiende bien que hace cada personaje de la historia.

Comment: @CandidMoe , no hay problema, gracias por tu tiempo